# You have to be inside an angular-cli project in order to use the build command after reinstall of angular-cli

Tags: angular-cli

I had the latest angular-cli installed globally and my project was building successfully.

While reading a suggested solution for another issue, (https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/917) I uninstalled the  global angular-cli and installed it as a dev-dependency.

That other issue wasn't solved so I uninstalled the dev-dependency and reinstalled angular-cli globally once again. 
Now when I try to do an **ng build** I'm getting the error:

*You have to be inside an angular-cli project in order to use the build command*

My angular-cli version did not change. Why isn't my project being recognised as an angular-cli project??

Comment: In my case, I had to update `@angular/cli` from 1.6.7 to 1.6.8

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Ok, found it.

**package.json** must contain a dependency to *angular-cli*.

When I uninstalled my local angular-cli, npm also removed the dependency entry.

Comment: could you explain with more detail that part about the dependency?

Comment: Uninstalling angular-cli as a dev dependency, ie  [ npm uninstall --save-dev angular-cli ] removed an entry from the packages.json  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.0.0", "..." } and therefore you need to ensure that this entry is available under "devDependencies" or even "dependencies" if necessary

Comment: So what you did? what exactly you uninstalled? -g or --save?

Answer (score 186):

Same as John Pankowicz answer, but in my case I had to run

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

for the versions to match.

Comment: It turns out "@angular/cli" is newer version of "angular-cli". The latter one is globally installed on my system and the former one is listed in package.json. After I replaced the package, it worked.

Comment: For me, only running the command npm install -g @angular/cli resolved the issue.

Comment: Yeah it Worked!

Comment: This worked for me as well. It was important for the project I was given to have matching versions

Comment: I was in WebAPI folder, so I had to switch to Angular CLI folder :)

Answer (score 61):

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli @angular/cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

use sudo on Mac/Linux.

Comment: npm ERR! As of npm@5, the npm cache self-heals from corruption issues and data extracted from the cache is guaranteed to be valid. If you want to make sure everything is consistent, use 'npm cache verify' instead.

Comment: If you face this issue:
Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" from....

Then, it might be useful to run as well:
npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular

Comment: for 2nd step use --force e.g `npm cache clean --force`

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 34):

It worked in my case

```
sudo npm uninstall -g angular-cli @angular/cli
sudo npm cache clean --force
npm install npm@latest -g
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Comment: `npm install npm@latest -g` may not be necessary

Comment: Thank you! 
This fixed it for me :)

Answer (score 27):

I had the same error message. But the cause and solution are slightly different. When I ran "ng -v" it showed different versions for angular-cli (1.0.0-beta.28.3) and @angular/cli (1.0.0-beta.31). I re-ran:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Now both show a version of 1.0.0-beta.31. The error message is gone and "ng serve" now works. (Yes - it was @angular/cli that I re-installed and the angular-cli version was updated.)

Comment: Note that it takes a _very_ long time to refresh angular-cli, even an hour. In the middle of a time-critical task it may doom your project.

Comment: For me I was trying npm install -g angular-cli, which is now deprecated. I had to npm install -g @angular/cli

Answer (score 15):

Use `npm install angular-cli --save-dev`

Comment: P.S This is now deprecated... angular-cli has officially moved to `@angular/cli`

Comment: Even it was deprecated fixed my issue. Cheers mate.

Answer (score 15):

Execute following commands step by step :

```
sudo npm uninstall -g angular-cli @angular/cli

sudo npm cache clean

npm install npm@latest -g

sudo npm install -g @angular/cli

npm rebuild node-sass --force
```

Answer (score 11):

This is what helped me when I found myself in the same problem:

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli @angular/cli
npm cache clean --force
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Answer (score 5):

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm uninstall --save angular-cli
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm uninstall --save @angular/cli
npm cache clean
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
```

Answer (score 5):

In my case (Mac OS X and previously used Angular 1.5 environment)

`npm -g cache clean --force`

`npm cache clean --force`

worked. (`npm install -g @angular/cli@latest` afterwards)

Answer (score 5):

It works with `npm install -g @angular/cli@latest` for me.

Answer (score 2):

> This error comes when there's incompatibility between node version and angular/cli version. therefore use below command to update the cli version to latest

**npm install -g @angular/cli@latest**

Answer (score 2):

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli @angular/cli

npm cache clean --force

npm install -g @angular-cli/latest
```

I had tried similar commands and work for me but make sure you use them from the command prompt with administrator rights

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue - it turned out that i was using a deprecated angular-cli instead of @angular/cli. The latter was used by my dev team and it took me some time to notice that we were using a different versions of angular-cli.

Answer (score 1):

Just include this in the package.json in devDependencies section

```
"angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.25.5"
```

Not compulsory to install it if you have another vresion of cli installed globally.

I got this issue when I worked with angular2 & 4 at a time with different project. So angular4 - need angular-cli@latest and angular2 need angular-cli the above version.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue while running my project:
I found out that if your project is using specific version of any thing in **package.json** find out that and install the specific version of that dependencies like for me, **npm install @angular/cli@^4.0.0**.

Answer (score 1):

It might be the problem with your version.

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

The above run worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Dont forget of to use --force:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem and nothing was working out but then I Followed below Steps and It worked for me.
when I ran **cmd** as administrator it worked fine for me.

1. First run the Command Prompt as administrator ans.
2. Create the new project.

If it still doesn't create the project, remove the folder and all it's files, and then run `ng new <project name>` followed by `ng serve`.

If nothing works just uninstall node and every other file related to it and follow the steps above

Answer (score 0):

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli 

npm install -g @angular/cli
```

That's it!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format >>>> code/errors/data as an image >> nothing. Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: Thank you for welcoming me. I will take care of it next time.