# I can't install latest version for angular-cli on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm trying to update my angular-cli version running

```
npm install -g angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.20-4
```

but when I run ng-v:  I'm get the error:

> Could not start watchman; falling back to NodeWatcher for file system events.
>
> Visit http://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#watchman for more info.
>
> angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.15
>
> node: 7.1.0
>
> os: linux x64

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

When you run `angular-cli` you have to run the same version globally as locally. I have had many problems with this. I do not know if this is how it is intended to run but I do know it causes problems for sure!

When installing globally you make sure you update local as well.

So what I do is,

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g angular-cli@latest
```

Then I remove the `npm_moduels` folder. Then I run,

```
 npm install angular-cli@latest --save
```

Now the local version and global version match.

Based on this method I would remove it from the package.json and once you run the final command to install it locally with --save it will add it back with the correct version.

**WARNING!**

When you update `angular-cli` it very well could break your app. If this happens check your other dependencies and make sure they work with the new version of `angular-cli` you are now running.

[Update Angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/Upgrading-from-Beta.10-to-Beta.14)

Comment: To expand on this a little, it's easier if you update the global angular-cli *outside* of any directory that has a `node_modules` folder. I somehow had a `node_modules/` in my home dir, and couldn't update the global cli from there for that reason.

Comment: As Oswaldo Salazar said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42460837/4345461) now it's *@angular/cli*, so it's: npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
Thanks :)