# An ejected project cannot use the build command anymore

Tags: angularjs, angular, sass, command-line-interface

I am new in Angular. I accidentally ejected my project using command-line, i don't remember which command i used. but when i try to run command

`ng serve --open`

it throws me an error of

> An ejected project cannot use the build command anymore.

I also re-installed angular-cli as said in [this Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39133782/you-have-to-be-inside-an-angular-cli-project-in-order-to-use-the-build-command-a) but no use.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

open the angular-cli.json, you should see this at the top

```
"project": {
   "name": "proj-name",
   "ejected": true,
}
```

remove the ejected part and it should work

Comment: The file is a hidden file in Ubuntu/UNIX. So, you have to open ".angular-cli.json"

Comment: Any why this is happened. Any configuration over written.

Comment: I ejected mine because I wanted to use a different optimizer.  I don't want to un-eject.  Any idea how I can build with an ejected webpack.config?

Answer (score 0):

once you ejected the project you will get a **webpack.config** file

And also you can see some commands in **package.json script** tag

```
"scripts": {
"ng": "ng",
"start": "webpack-dev-server --port=4200",
"build": "webpack",
"test": "karma start ./karma.conf.js",
"lint": "ng lint",
"e2e": "protractor ./protractor.conf.js",
"pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false --quiet"
```

},

you can still run the project by using **npm start**

you can still build the project by using **npm run build**

Comment: when running 'npm start' - Getting error as- module.js:557
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '@ngtools/webpack'